# Control a usb port from the command line using shell scripts

Tags: macos, shell

Background: I have these usb lights that I want to turn on and off based on notifications (like build failures).

I figured the easiest way to do is have the lights plugged into the usb port and just mount/unmount based on emails received. On a mac, a usb plugged in device does not come as a mounted drive.

Have any cool tips to build your own build monitor?

Comment: I've tried using a usb hub as well, but unfortunately that doesn't show up either. Anyone know of a device acting as a usb hub and shows up as a mountable drive?

Answer (score 1):

My impression is that most such devices are just drawing power from the USB port, and don't have any particular software presence.  As such, turning them off via software would require figuring out how to disable power to a particular USB port.  While probably not impossible, that's not necessarily the sort've thing that's going to be exposed in a convenient high-level API.

Answer (score 1):

I've got no idea what device you've got, but only drives (like USB sticks, external hard drives, MP3 players, etc.) can be mounted. Or would you expect your mouse to be mountable?

There is no generic command line tool I know of to interface with USB in a way you like and I can't imagine one as it's not as simple as, say, a plain old serial or parallel port. With USB, devices come in different device classes (like audio and printer) and one them means essentially *proprietary communication* and can be anything. Even with the generic classes, communication is already very complex.

So you would need to get documentation for these lights (how they are to be controlled) and if there isn't already a dedicated tool that does support these lights you would need to write one yourself.